# NullPointerException with simpleAdapter in android

Tags: java, android

I am using a simpleAdapter to create a listview, however I get this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.tab.Activity.onCreate(Activity.java:36)
```

and this the code that I am using:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
 private SimpleAdapter notes;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout);

    notes = new SimpleAdapter( 
            this, 
            list,
            R.layout.display_layout,
            new String[] { "line1" },
            new int[] { R.id.text1}  );
   ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
   lv.setAdapter( notes );
}
```

line 36 would be

```
new int[] { R.id.text1}  );
```

text1 is defined, so why I am getting nullpointer error?

Comment: Are you sure this is the correct line? Could it be lv.setAdapter? Is R.id.listview defined?

Comment: is R.id.text1 really an **int**?

Comment: Stack trace and the layout file `display_layout.xml` might be helpful.

Comment: R.id is always an int. Eclipse would give an error if it is otherwise. I am wondering does the class in which SimpleAdapter is used have to be extended from ListActivity only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved the issue by implementing new SimpleAdapter following this tutorial:
http://kurtchen.com/blog/2010/07/30/use-simpleadapter-to-make-a-list-with-icons/

I think the problem was that "ArrayList list" variable was null and therefore SimpleAdapter could not map any value to the "R.id.text1" column.

Thank you all for your answers

Answer (score 0):

If the evaluation of

```
new int[] { R.id.text1 }
```

results in a `NullPointerException` it is due to the fact that `R.id` is null.

The exception would also arise if `R.id` happened to be an `Integer` which was `null`.

Comment: I believe we can assume that **R.id.text1** is not **null** because it appears to be an **int**. It points to **R.id** being null.

Comment: That's why I wrote from a "pure java perspective" (where `R.id.text1` could very well be an Integer). (Reformulated anyway)

Comment: In Android context, it should be autogenerated int.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    notes = new SimpleAdapter(this, list, R.layout.display_layout,
            new String[] { "line1" }, new int[] { android.R.id.text1 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the value of `R.id` is returning null. Try:

```
new int[] { ((R.id !=null && R.id.text1 >-1)?R.id.text1 :-1)};
```

Edit

I am using `-1` to assume zero could be an valid value.